# PostgreSQL create table fails on identity column

Tags: postgresql, create-table, dbeaver

I'm trying to set up a Postgres table using DBeaver as my management tool to run queries.  Everything seems to work OK until I try to generate a table with an identity column.  I am getting this error:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "GENERATED"

This is the query that is failing:

```
create table public.test (
    id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY 
)
```

This query works just fine:

```
create table public.test (
    id INT
)
```

I referenced data [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-identity-column/) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createtable.html) to make sure the syntax was correct. What's going on?

EDIT:  My problem was that my version is too old: 9.5.18 - needs to be 10 for this command to work.

Comment: Are you on Postgres 10 or later?  This was introduced in 10.  Before that use `int serial primary key`.

Comment: Mike, that was my problem, thanks!   My version is 9.5.18

Comment: My pleasure, sir!